# ffmpeg on Linux - convert video to play on iPhone [solved]

Tags: ffmpeg, video, conversion, ios

I am converting Hi8 to `.mkv`, `.mp4` or `.avi` using ffmpeg on Linux (Gentoo).

I am trying to convert small clips to play on an iPhone, iPad (iOS)

The following will convert but it will not play on an iPhone.

```
ffmpeg -i troy1.mkv -strict -2 santa2.m4v
```

Please throw me a bone.

Answer (score 0):

Solved after installing ffmpeg again with x265 and h265:

```
ffmpeg -i troy1.mkv -c:v libx265 -crf 26 -preset fast -c:a aac -b:a 128k -tag:v hvc1 santa11.MOV
```